# ModuleNotFoundError after installing h5py

Tags: macos, installation, apple-m1, h5py

[Installed h5py on my macOS m1, but I still get ModuleNotFoundError.

> pip install h5py
> ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCmxz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Many of such cases happen when you have multiple python installed in machine, package installed using one and searched for in another. I installed `h5py 3.7.0` and `pip list` shows it in the list.